# svg.selectAll("[#trk*_sldrs_r]"); regular expression correct syntax?

Tags: d3.js

I got

`var t = svg.selectAll("[id^='t']");`

to bring back all elements whose id starts with "t". However my

`var t = svg.selectAll("[#trk*_sldrs_r]");`

errors and does not bring back elements with ids of "`trk1_sldrs_r`" and "`trk2_sldrs_r`". Appreciate the correct syntax. Thanks.

Comment: The selectors aren't regular expressions, they're [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). I would assign a class to everything you want to select and select by that class.

Comment: Have 120 sliders each with mute and solo, each with filter bank of 5 buttons (all svg rects). I need to d3.select e.g. all 120 solo buttons and ascertain which are "on" (stroke-width 4). I have named everything e.g. id = "trk1_solo", "trk2_solo" in Inkscape. Would you give all 120 a class of "solo", all 120 mutes a class of "mute" etc? Are not d3 selectors actually css selectors in which regexpr can be used,  as in my successful ("[id^='t']");? Is it not possible to select with a wildcard char regexpr, or is it just a much superior solution to class everything in Inkscape? tia.

Comment: CSS selectors don't do full regular expressions AFAIK. You can select by attribute though, so you could get all elements with stroke-width equal to 4: `[stroke-width=4]`.

Comment: I am not sure if you can select multiple elements that have the same id. At least, this is what you are trying to do with the selector "#*******"

Comment: they do not have the same id - the "*" is meant to be a regexpr wildcard to find ids of "trk1_sldrs_r" and "trk2_sldrs_r", although pretty sure my syntax of "[#trk*_sldrs_r]" is wrong. As Lars suggested I am now retrieving by e.g. class "trksldrs_r" but would like to know whether the regexpr can work. Do not have .attr as svg elements loaded from file, not created by d3.select(etc).